# Run custom npm command in Powershell on VSTS hosted build agent

Tags: powershell, npm, azure-pipelines, npm-scripts

I need to iteratively run an npm command and want to do it from a PowerShell task in a VSTS build step. I cannot use `"npm <command>"` in PowerShell and have also tried to run commands using `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "<command>"` and `Invoke-Expression "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "<command>"` in the PowerShell on the VSTS hosted build agent. How can I run npm commands from a PowerShell build step?

Additionally, the `<command>` is a custom script from my package.json file. It does not need to be custom. I only put it there to call in a custom npm VSTS build step.

Comment: if you click on "add a build step" and go to the "package" category, there should be an npm option. does this meet your needs?

Comment: Is there a npm.exe? Do you know whether that's there during the build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call npm command directly through PowerShell task with Hosted agent.

Make sure the **Working folder** (package.json folder path) of **PowerShell** task is right.

Regarding custom script in package.json, you need to call it like `npm run [script key]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I set the correct working folder path then? I run into this problem with the package.json path: `##[error]npm ERR! path D:\a\1\s\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\package.json'` The PowerShell is in the same dir as the package.json

Comment: I fixed this by: (1) calling the command from PowerShell as you suggested as `npm run [script key]` and (2) updating the "Working folder" reference in the advanced options of the PowerShell VSTS build task to point to where the PS modules I wrote are (I run the `npm run [script key]` in one of these modules). _The main PS script is in the same folder as the package.json, but the PS modules with the `npm run [script key]` are in a child directory._

Answer (score 2):

You can call the npm command with the Start-Process and supplying the arguments through -ArgumentList switch seperated by commas

example Start-Process npm  -ArgumentList "run","build" -wait
the -wait switch will wait for the task to be completed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).